# How to group rows in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, rows

After I have decided a starting row and an ending row earlier on in my code, I am having trouble grouping all of the rows between the start and end. Both my start_row and end_row variables are Integers.

(start_row and end_row are the variables, wS is my worksheet)
A few of the things I have already tried:

```
- wS.Rows("start_row" & ":" & "end_row").Group
- wS.Rows("5:6").Group '(just did this to test)
```

I either get a type mismatch or application defined error. I believe my syntax for grouping is wrong, so if someone could help that would be so helpful. Thanks

Comment: Don't enclose variables within quotes. Also `Long` is preferable over `Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wS.Rows(start_row & ":" & end_row).Group
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this.

```
wS.Rows(start_row & ":" & end_row).Group
wS.Rows("5:6").Group
```

Comment: @BigBen Yes you are absolutely right my mistake. `wS.Rows("5:6").Group` is the right syntax.